# What is the meaning of the phrase "it is to put on someone"?

Tags: grammar

I have found that phrase in a [lingohack](https://youtu.be/7N2eRkMnKsk) from the BBC. Here it goes:

> Skin displays developed by Japanese reserchers that show your vital signs. It is to put on patients, so that doctors can monitor their progress.

It is quite understandble from the context that the technology will be put on patients, but I cannot understand why *be* was left out, for example:

> It is to **be** put on patients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say of some candies set out on a table "they are to eat" or "they are to be eaten". The article chose the former, whereas you're asking for the latter.